# Running multiple features sequentially in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, tags, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline

Can anyone provide some help on running below features(@reg1 and @reg2 are tags for each feature file) sequentially through a Pipeline script? I have the below lines as part of my pipeline script. The problem is when the first one fails it stops there. I want it to go and run the second one even if the first one fails as the features a mutually exclusive.

```
Stages {

        stage('First set of Tests') {
            steps {
                dir('dir1') {
                    sh 'mvn clean verify -Dtarget.env="test-env" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@reg1'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Second set of Tests') {
            steps {
                dir('dir1') {
                    sh 'mvn clean verify -Dtarget.env="test-env" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@reg2"'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your stps in parallel. Looks official documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel)
There are some useful examples.

For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('Test On Windows') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat "run-tests.bat"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Test On Linux') {
                    agent {
                        label "linux"
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh "run-tests.sh"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```